# sf2 - list of all groups with information if user joined this group

Tags: symfony, orm, entity, entities

I start to model the db/entities in symfony2.
I have two entities. First is a User and second is a Groups.
I want to connect both. I think I should use many to many relations(?).

But my major problem is how can I get list of all groups with information if user joined this group.

Group Entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="GroupBundle\Entity\Group">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="50"/>
        <field name="description" type="string" column="description"/>
        <many-to-many field="users" mapped-by="groups" target-entity="AccountBundle\Entity\User"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

and User Entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="AccountBundle\Entity\User">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <field name="username" type="string" column="username" length="255"/>
        <field name="password" type="string" column="password" length="255"/>
        <field name="salt" type="string" column="salt" length="255"/>
        <field name="email" type="string" column="email" length="255"/>
        <field name="active" type="boolean" column="active"></field>
        <field name="token" type="string" column="token" length="255"/>
        <field name="lastLoginTime" type="datetime" column="lastLoginTime" nullable="true"/>
        <field name="registerTime" type="datetime" column="registerTime"/>
        <one-to-many field="events" target-entity="CoreBundle\Entity\Event" mapped-by="user" />
        <many-to-many field="groups" inversed-by="users" target-entity="GroupBundle\Entity\Group">
        <join-table name="UserGroups">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="userId" referenced-column-name="id" />
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="groupId" referenced-column-name="id" />
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

There is no relation between there yet because I don't know what is best.
Maybe I must create additional Entity between like UserGroup?

D4V1D you have a right. Assumption is: User can join to many group and group can have a many user.

Okey I add the many-to-many relations. I hope I did it right.

And now. This is fragment of my controller:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository("GroupBundle\Entity\Group");
    $groups = $repo->findAll();

    $user = $this->getUser();
    $user_groups = $user->getGroups();


    foreach($user_groups as $user_group){
        /* @var $group Group */
        foreach($groups as $group){
            if($group->getId() == $user_group->getId()){
                $group->setUserInGroup(true); // of course i extend my entity file about extra set and get method.
            }
        }        
    }

    return $this->render('GroupBundle:showAll.html.twig', array('groups' => $groups));
```

and view:

```
{% for group in groups %}
<div>
    {{ group.name }}
    {% if(group.getUserInGroup()) %}
      <a href="#">join</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>    
{% endfor %}
```

I try find the best and right method to do this.

Comment: Is a Group of Roles or what??? You need to post more info about the relationship type between them

Comment: Maybe should you post some code of both your `User` and `Group` entities. We easily guess that many `Users` can joined many `Groups` and `Groups` can have many `Users` but we need some of your code.

Comment: Guys you have a right. I added some code.

Answer (score 0):

Without relation OneToMany with user and group, how do you join the group with user? which field have this information? you need a relation yes.

Group entity :

```
<many-to-many field="users" target-entity="AccountBundle\Entity\User" mapped-by="groups" />
```

User entity :

```
<many-to-many field="groups" target-entity="GroupBundle\Entity\Group" inversed-by="users"/>
```

Comment: I know that I must add the relations. I didn't do that because I don't know which one. I wrote about this. I edit my post and add relations based on you suggest. But still do not know how to get list of all groups with information if the logged user is in group.

I need list all groups and add he button to join if the logged user is not yet in the group.

Comment: update your question with your controller action where you want to get the groups , you should implement your getter setter in then you can get information about that user group or list all groups with the repository, i help you do that but need to see your action first

Comment: Thanks. I do that when I come back home. Are you sure I should use many-to-one/one-to-many relations instead many-to-many?

Or maybe I should use intermediate Entity liek UserGroup?
If I will use one-to-many is not replicate my group entries in db?

[Example](https://atlas.mindmup.com/2015/03/cd115c90b5dd013203cc3a7e0739ca51/entitys_example/index.html)

Comment: it depends if you want a user to have multiple group? then manytomany, no need for intermediate entity

Comment: I have a UserA, UserB and UserC. I have a Gruops: CatsFan, DogsFan and UnicornsFan - each group is one to all user. The user can join to many group. Is on this case I need create intermediate Entity like UserGroup [UserId <---> GroupId] and use many-to-many?

Comment: use many to many your users can have groups as an arraycollection , for example $user->getGroups() will return array of groups that he joined, or $group->getUsers() will return array of users who are in the group

Comment: I edit my post with new code and fragment of controller

Comment: your code looks fine now, you showing all groups name for user to join, what else do you need? for showing user groups you can do it in twig  {% for usergroup in app.user.groups %}
<div>
    {{ usergroup .name }} </div> {%endfor%}

Comment: But I don't want show all groups and all user group separately. I want marge it. I do that (post edited), but I wonder if I did it right. Maybe is better way to do this.

Comment: what do you mean by merge it? all groups means all groups including the one that are joined by the user. if you want to list all groups and show the ones that are joined by user do a check in the twig like this inside your groups loop {% for usergroup in app.user.groups %} {% if usergroup.id == group.id %} <span>'you already joined this group'</span> {%endif%}{% endfor %}